# How to pass object from D to C++?

Tags: c++, interop, d, dmd, ldc

I'm trying to make an interop with C++ and D. And the thing I've found today is really messing my mind: objects are not being passed correctly in my program.

It's better to show an example.

I have a C++ library, which I compile to an object file and the D program, which I link with my library and run.

Here they are:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Color
{
public:
  Color(unsigned int _r, unsigned int _g, unsigned int _b) : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b) {}

  unsigned int r, g, b;
};

class Printer
{
public:
  Printer() {}
  ~Printer() {}
  static Printer* getInstance();
  void print(Color *c);
};

Printer* Printer::getInstance()
{
  return new Printer();
}

void Printer::print(Color *c)
{
  printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", c->r, c->g, c->b);
}
```

And the D program:

```
import std.stdio;

extern(C++)
{
  class Color
  {
    uint r, g, b;

    this(uint _r, uint _g, uint _b)
    {
      r = _r;
      g = _g;
      b = _b;
    }
  }

  class Printer
  {
    @disable this();
    static Printer getInstance();
    final void print(Color c);
  }
}

void main()
{
  auto printer = Printer.getInstance();

  Color c = new Color(42, 7, 19);

  printer.print(c);
}
```

I compile them with these commands:

```
c++ -c my_core.cpp -o my_core.o
dmd main.d my_core.o -L-lstdc++
```

But when I run `./main`, I got strange results:

```
(113244372, 1, 42)
```

What made me think objects are being passed incorrectly is just a simple experiment. First, I ran my program a couple of times and here's what I saw:

```
$ ./main
(266442332, 1, 42)
$ ./main
(234899036, 1, 42)
$ ./main
(109475420, 1, 42)
```

So the first number seems to be a pointer to a memory block. And my sixth feeling in couple with assembly knowledge make me think it's the pointer to `this` variable.

And now, just to confirm my data is still in place and those numbers are not just random ones, I've added two more fields to my class `Color`:

C++ lib:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Color
{
public:
  Color(unsigned int _r, unsigned int _g, unsigned int _b, unsigned int _u, unsigned int _v) : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b), u(_u), v(_v) {}

  unsigned int r, g, b, u, v;
};

class Printer
{
public:
  Printer() {}
  ~Printer() {}
  static Printer* getInstance();
  void print(Color *c);
};

Printer* Printer::getInstance()
{
  return new Printer();
}

void Printer::print(Color *c)
{
  printf("(%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", c->r, c->g, c->b, c->u, c->v);
}
```

And the D program:

```
import std.stdio;

extern(C++)
{
  class Color
  {
    this(uint _r, uint _g, uint _b, uint _u, uint _v)
    {
      r = _r;
      g = _g;
      b = _b;
      u = _u;
      v = _v;
    }

    uint r, g, b, u, v;
  }

  class Printer
  {
    @disable this();
    static Printer getInstance();
    final void print(Color c);
  }
}

void main()
{
  auto printer = Printer.getInstance();

  Color c = new Color(42, 7, 19, 499, 727);

  printer.print(c);
}
```

And the outputs are:

```
$ ./main                         
(90379876, 1, 42, 7, 19)
$ ./main
(79758948, 1, 42, 7, 19)
$ ./main
(74901092, 1, 42, 7, 19)
$ ./main
(217458276, 1, 42, 7, 19)
$ ./main
(238933604, 1, 42, 7, 19)
```

I've tried compiling my program with both DMD and LDC compilers, but both provided me with exactly the same behavior.

**UPD:** What's even more interesting and *(probably)* pointing to where the problem lies, is the fact objects, created in C++ lib are being passed between D and C++ correctly.

To prove this, I created "factory method" in my `Color` class:

```
static Color* create(unsigned int _r, unsigned int _g, unsigned int _b, unsigned int _u, unsigned int _v) {
    return new Color(_r, _g, _b, _u, _v);
}
```

And then, in D program:

```
Color c = Color.create(42, 7, 19, 499, 727);

printer.print(c);
```

So that the `c` object comes from C++ library, gets passed to the `printer` object, created in C++ library and this transfer is made in D program.

And the results are unexpectedly correct:

```
$ ./main
(42, 7, 19, 499, 727)
```

Am I missing the concepts of C++ and D interop or is this a bug in two D compilers *(doubtfully)*?

Comment: AFAIK this is by design. D is capable of interfacing to C++ but it can't create C++ objects on its own (and D objects have different binary layout). Using factory method seems correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should't use Ds new to allocate C++ classes, if you create a Color::getInstance it works.

```
import std.stdio;

extern(C++)
{
  class Color
  {
    this(uint _r, uint _g, uint _b, uint _u, uint _v)
    {
      r = _r;
      g = _g;
      b = _b;
      u = _u;
      v = _v;
    }

    uint r, g, b, u, v;
    static Color getInstance(uint _r, uint _g, uint _b, uint _u, uint _v);
  }

  class Printer
  {
    @disable this();
    static Printer getInstance();
    final void print(Color c);
  }
}

void main()
{
  auto printer = Printer.getInstance();
  auto c = Color.getInstance(42, 7, 19, 499, 727);

  printer.print(c);
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Color
{
public:
  Color(unsigned int _r, unsigned int _g, unsigned int _b, unsigned int _u, unsigned int _v) : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b), u(_u), v(_v) {}

  unsigned int r, g, b, u, v;
  static Color* getInstance (unsigned int _r, unsigned int _g, unsigned int _b, unsigned int _u, unsigned int _v);
};

Color* Color::getInstance(unsigned int _r, unsigned int _g, unsigned int _b, unsigned int _u, unsigned int _v)
{
  return new Color(_r, _g, _b, _u, _v);
}

class Printer
{
public:
  Printer() {}
  ~Printer() {}
  static Printer* getInstance();
  void print(Color *c);
};

Printer* Printer::getInstance()
{
  return new Printer();
}

void Printer::print(Color *c)
{
  printf("(%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", c->r, c->g, c->b, c->u, c->v);
}
```

Comment: But that sounds like problem bypassing, doesn't it?.. There is a reference on the D docs: http://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html#memory-allocation saying `Leaving a pointer to it on the stack (as a parameter or automatic variable)` *(...is a solution to this kind of problems...)*

Comment: That is for objects allocated with the GC to prevent them from being collected because the GC doesn't know that C++ still has references to those objects. For example, if you store a GC allocated object on a C++ array.